# How to register generic interfaces in http client?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, httpclient

In my aspnet core project I am using HttpClient, I have generic interface and class as well, but I can not register them in startup.

My interface looks like:

```
public interface IHttpClientWrapper<T> where  T : class
{
        Task<T> GetAsync(string url, string authType, string token, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

My class look like:

```
    public class HttpClientWrapper<T> : IHttpClientWrapper<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public HttpClientWrapper(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(string url, string authType, string token,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authType, token);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

            using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request,
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                cancellationToken))
            {
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return stream.ReadAndDeserializeFromJson<T>();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
 services.AddHttpClient<IHttpClientWrapper<T>, HttpClientWrapper<T>>()
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(handler =>
                    new HttpClientHandler
                     {
                     AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip
                   });
```

What I tried and it was failed:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IHttpClientWrapper<>),typeof(HttpClientWrapper<>)).ConfigureOptions(
                new HttpClientHandler
                {  
                    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip
                });
```

In short I need to somehow register AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip it can be with Transient if possible

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Why don't [use `HttpClientFactory` and typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm not sure why you registering IHttpClientWrapper. If it's transient, then you can you can just create it when you need it.
2. If you have a good reason to use DI for it then you could make the class non-generic and make the method generic:

```
public interface IHttpClientWrapper
{
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url, string authType, string token, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: `ou can you can just create it when you need it.` if that was the case there'd be no need for `AddTransient`. It's needed because classes use dependencies even if they aren't long lived. In this particular case `HttpClient`'s lifetime and most importantly, pooling, is controlled by HttpClientFactory

Comment: Generic types *can* be registered too This is used by ASP.NET Core itself, it's not an aberration. This really isn't a good answer.

Comment: "This really isn't a good answer" isn't a good comment :) Seriously though, what is wrong about it? I really think that a) a transient HttpClient isn't great and b) a generic method better encapsulates what is needed. If want to make two calls would you ask for two wrappers? (And yes, ILogger<T> is an example of a generic interface in DI).